# Why do these checkboxes work in Safari but not Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that creates dynamic SVG based on checkboxes a user selects. The SVG updates every time the user checks or unchecks a company from the list of checkboxes.

I have a problem with checkboxes in my javascript form handling or CSS. On a Mac, the checkboxes work well in Safari. But not in Chrome or Firefox:

https://www.versionmuseum.com/dh/checkboxes-dont-work

The main CSS file in production is likely the culprit, but I am not CSS-savvy enough to fix the issue.
https://www.versionmuseum.com/assets/css/main.css

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I highly suggest you add `relevant` code here in Stackoverflow web site within you question...

Comment: I don't see them working well on Safari as well. It's the exact same behaviour in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Is there a reason why initially you set for `input[type="checkbox"]` -> `-moz-appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none; -ms-appearance: none; appearance: none;` and `opacity: 0; z-index: -1;` ?

Comment: The css file is from a template from pixelarity.com. I didn't hand-craft it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually in the html. The `for=` attribute of the `<label>` element needs to match the `id=` element of the `<input>` element, in order for clicking the label to change the checkbox state.

So for example, you have:

```
<label class="checkbox-label">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="company" value="Apple" checked="">
        <label for="human">Apple</label>
      </label>
```

but it should be:

```
<label class="checkbox-label">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="company" value="Apple" checked id="human-apple">
    <label for="human-apple">Apple</label>
</label>
```

And of course remember that ids must be unique on the page.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Thank you so much! I upvoted it but don't have the reputation score to make the # change publicly.